# Cocoapods 0.36.beta.2 unable to use GooglePlus SDKs - Undefined symbols for architecture

Tags: ios, swift, google-plus, cocoapods

After updating to Cocoapods 0.36 beta 2 I experienced following problems in my Swift project:

I am not able to import `googleplus-ios-sdk` the old way, in my bridging header file:

```
#import <GooglePlus/GooglePlus.h> //--> FILE NOT FOUND
#import <GoogleOpenSource/GoogleOpenSource.h> //--> FILE NOT FOUND
```

Which seems to be ok, as for other pods (having the same issue when imported in bridging header) I can simply import proper frameworks in my swift source code files.

When trying to import Google frameworks in swift it works like expected:

```
import google_plus_ios_sdk //--> OK, no error here
```

...but it gives me an compilation error when trying to use any of Google's SDK class:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GPPURLHandler", referenced from:
  __TMaCSo13GPPURLHandler in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am able to integrate most of my old, Obj-C pods without an issue, but this one causing problems like described above. I have already cleaned up project, as well as removed all files stored in Xcode's DeliveredData directory but it didn't solve the problems.

Is there something I am doing wrong, or it's the problem inside the `google-plus-ios-sdk` pods? If so, are there any steps I could make to fix it?

**Update** it looks like FacebookSDK issue was fixed in version 3.22. I have updated description above, as problem is not connected with Facebook SDK anymore.

Comment: I had a similar problem last week on a different library, with a link error. The only solution I found is to use the latest stable version. So if you don't need the beta (are you creating a swift pod?) I suggest doing the same.

Comment: I definitely want to use framework generation that comes with cocoapods 0.36. I was using stable version before, but eventually I need to move to 0.36 anyway. One last problem I have is with GooglePlusSDK.

Comment: could you please post 'pod install' log ? Are there are some wanings?

Comment: I opened an issue for that problem on Cocoapods' github: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3106